# Getting Columns of Row which is inside a List

Tags: java, list, row

I have a List which is having rows fetched from the JDBC.
I am iterating over the List like

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
                myList.get(i);// it returns me Row
                // I want to get the column value with column index.
}
```

Please let me know how can I get all the column values of that row by indexes.

Thanks,
KP

Comment: Can you print your list.

Comment: Yes, I can print my list but the rows will come as encoded format as package.myPOJOClass@1bw,.....,,,. Something like this. And I dont want to assign this row to pojo because I want the code to be generic.

Comment: have you added POJO in array list with database column values set to it right? so why you are not using **getter method** to access the value. **for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){POJO p = myList.get(i); p.getColumnName(); }**

Comment: I dont want to use POJO, as my code should be generic for multiple POJO's